# How to create and implement an authorization filter in a .NET Core application

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization

I am trying to figure out how to use authorization filters  to authorize users before acting on requests in a .Net Core 2.1 application.

Users at my company get redirected through an SSO server when using in-house web applications that require authentication. The SSO server then forwards requests to the web application with the authentication and authorization information in the request headers. Currently, all of my controller action methods contain a conditional statement that checks to see if the user roles provided in the request header contain any of the possible roles required for performing the action. Making use of authorization filters seems like a much cleaner way to go, but in spite of all of the documentation and tutorials I've seen, I still can't figure out how to implement that technique.

Here is the method that I currently use to check if a user is authorized to perform an action:

```
using System;

namespace MyApp
{
    public static class Authorization
    {
        public static bool IsAuthorized(string usersRoles, params string[] authorizedRoles)
        {
            if (usersRoles != null)
            {
                foreach (string authorizedRole in authorizedRoles)
                {
                    if (usersRoles.Contains(",MYAPP?" + authorizedRole))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an example of a controller method that passes user roles from the request headers and a list of possible roles to the "IsAuthorized" method to check if the user is authorized to perform the action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if (!Authorization.IsAuthorized(Request.Headers["COMPANYACCESSROLES"], "TYPE1_USER", "TYPE2_USER", "TYPE3_USER"))
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Not Authorized";
        return View("MyAppMessage");
    }
    // Do stuff to complete the action requested here
    return View();
}
```

The roles contained in the request header look something like this:

```
SOMEAPP,SOMEAPP?SOMEROLE1,SOMEAPP?SOMEROLE2,MYAPP,MYAPP?TYPE2_USER,MYAPP?TYPE2_RO,ANOTHERAPP,ANOTHERAPP?ANOTHERROLE1
```

I'd like to be able to remove the conditional statements that I currently have at the beginning of each controller method and use authorization filters like this instead:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "TYPE1_USER", "TYPE2_USER", "TYPE3_USER")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Do stuff to complete the action requested here
    return View();
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Request.Headers["COMPANYACCESSROLES"]` has nothing to do with security. It suggests that the client can set any role it wants and the server won't be able to detect the change. It would be more secure to set a bearer token in the Authorization header. In that case you can use the Authorize attribute to specify the allowed role per controller / method, as you like. As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles).

Comment: The access roles that are supplied in the request header come by way of an SSO server which authenticates users at my company. I have updated my question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user's access roles are included in the request header from an SSO server, an action filter can be used instead of an authorization filter for allowing access. Adding an IActionFilter class nested inside a TypeFilterAttribute class to the project does the trick:

```
public class AuthorizedRoles : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AuthorizedRoles(params string[] authorizedRoles) : base(typeof(AuthorizationFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { authorizedRoles };
    }

    private class AuthorizationFilter: IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly string[] _authorizedRoles;

        public AuthorizationFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, string[] authorizedRoles)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AuthorizedRoles>();
            _authorizedRoles = authorizedRoles;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            string usersRoles = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["BOEINGACCESSROLES"];
            if (!Authorization.IsAuthorized(usersRoles, _authorizedRoles))
            {
                context.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NotAuthorized" };
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that I don't know of a good way to pass ViewData information to a Razor page from within the IActionFilter class, so when a user is not authorized, instead of setting `ViewData["Message"] = "Not Authorized"` and calling the "MyAppMessage" view, a static "NotAuthorized" view is called from the `OnActionExecuting` method.

A filter like this can now be used above the controller method (or above the entire controller class, if desired) to only allow access to users that have at least one of the specified roles:

```
[AuthorizedRoles("TYPE1_USER", "TYPE2_USER", "TYPE3_USER")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Do stuff to complete the action requested here
    return View();
}
```